# Hikashop Add a shoping cart icon on navbar

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm working on website using Hikashop on Joomla.
how can i display a cart icon in main navbar, with notification of products added in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hikashop cart module and use the mini cart option. After that make a new position inside your joomla template file next to your navbar. If this doesn't work you can use css to position it next to the navbar.